# Unable to print value in Description : Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger onAccountInsert on Account (before update) { 
    List<Account> AccOppData = new List<Account>();    
    Integer i = 0;
    AccOppData = [Select ID, (SELECT ID FROM Opportunities) FROM Account WHERE Account.ID IN : trigger.oldMap.keyset()]; 
    for(Account a : AccOppData)
    {    i = 0;
         for(Opportunity opp : a.Opportunities){ i++; }
         a.Description = String.valueOf(i);
    }  
}
```

Comment: are you getting an error? if so, what is it?

Comment: @AdamMichaelDaw - I am not getting any error.. but the value is not getting stored in Description.

Comment: There's nothing that ties the account you are setting the description on to the trigger context, so there's nothing updating the account.

Comment: @AdamMichaelDaw -  Yes. I am trying to figure out a way to bind to the trigger context variable. Or if there is other way an update to description can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a record to be updated in a before context, you need to iterate over the records in "trigger.new".

So, for your code:

```
trigger onAccountInsert on Account (before update) { 
    Map<Id, Account> AccOppData = new Map<Id, Account>();    
    AccOppData = new Map<Id, Account>([Select ID, (SELECT ID FROM Opportunities) FROM Account WHERE Account.ID IN : trigger.oldMap.keyset()]); 
    for(Account a : trigger.new){    
      a.Description = AccOppData.get(a.Id).Opportunities.size();
    }  
}
```